# Embed XSD files in one (binary) file

Tags: c++, windows

Our C++ project uses ~30 XSD files for validation of XML messages.

For deployment we would like to have all XSD files embedded in one file. Additionally it would be nice, if the file would be binary, so the XSD schemas cannot be viewed easily.

Is there a solution for Windows (additional Linux support would be nice, but no requirement) to embed multiple text files in one big binary file and use it for a C++ application?

Comment: There are lots of archive formats.  Some even have direct support for encrypting their contents if you want to make them harder to read.

Comment: Are you talking how to install or how to obfuscate?

Comment: Look perhaps into [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible Windows-specific solution is to create resource-only DLL with all your XSDs (or any other files).

Use below links for details.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/creating-a-resource-only-dll

> Additionally it would be nice, if the file would be binary, so the XSD
>   schemas cannot be viewed easily.

Resources in dll\exe are not encrypted and anybody will be able to read them using resource viewer